# Get all elements from Lists inside a List

Tags: c#, litedb

I have following data model:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        [BsonId]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        [BsonId]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        [BsonRef("customers")] 
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cart
    {
        [BsonId]
        public int CartID { get; set; }
        public List<Order> OrderList { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to access the customers via queries on my cart collection.
I tried something like this:

```
var collectionCarts = db.GetCollection<Cart>("carts");
var result = collectionCarts.Include("OrderList.Customer").Find(x => x.OrderList[0].Customer.CustomerId == 2);
```

However, all attempts result in an empty customer object. My database, which I checked with the LiteDB-Viewer seems to be OK.

Answer (score 5):

You could get the Customers like this:

```
using System.Linq;

collectionCarts.SelectMany(c => c.OrderList.Select(o => o.Customer));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. What is the the `carts` objects which you start with? `var carts = db.GetCollection<Cart>("carts");` ?

Comment: It's showing that there is no definition for the method "Select"

Comment: You need to include the namespace `System.Linq` (See my edit). I've also changed to `collectionCarts`. I thought that this would be an enumerable collection of `Cart` objects.

Comment: I have Linq added. The syntax seems to work, but there are still empty customer objects (null) as they cant be extracted from the litedb database correctly I assume.

Comment: That will have some other reason. This Linq query will give you all `Customer` objects with the `CustomerId` 2 from all `OrderLists` from all `Carts` in the collection

Comment: Yes I checked this with `var allCarts = collectionCarts.FindAll();` With your expression on the `allCarts`object the correct objects are excluded, but the the customer field is null.

Comment: I didn't use LightDB yet. Is there perhaps an issue with lazy loading?

Comment: I don't know, but it seems to not store sub-documents (customers) in the returning objects.

Comment: Seems like another question to me ;-)

Comment: Thanks! SelectMany is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check only for the first item in the list, or for any item in the list? 
Because in your query, you are explicitly querying for the first one only.

If not (as I assume), try something like this:

```
var result = collectionCarts.Include("OrderList.Customer").
                    Find(x => x.Select(v => v.OrderList).Select(v =>v.Customer).
                                     Select(v => v.CustomerId).ToList().Contains(2));
```

Comment: Again an error that there is no definiton for `Select`

Comment: I see....   How about:  var result = collectionCarts.Include("OrderList.Customer").Find(Query.Contains("OrderList.$.Customer.$.CustomerId", 2));

Comment: This doesn't bring my any results.

Comment: Or even:  var result = collectionCarts.Include("OrderList.Customer").Select(v => v.OrderList).Select(v => v.Customer).Find(x => x.CustomerId == 2);

Comment: There is the `Select not found` problem again